# Improve SQL query for removing rows that appear more than N times

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation

Is there a better to do the following?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE CONCAT(a, b, c, d)  NOT IN 
(
  SELECT CONCAT(a, b, c, d) AS result
  FROM table
  GROUP BY result
  HAVING COUNT(*) < 40
)
```

I have also tried using some joins, but ran out of memory. What I am trying to do, is if a,b,c,d are repeated 40 times or more, ignore that data, otherwise return. Eventually I spit out the result to a CSV.

**EDIT: EXAMPLE DATA**

```
A  |B  |C  |D
---|---|---|---
123|ABC|ccc|ddd
123|ABC|ccc|ddd
... (40 times)
456|qwe|qqq|www
789|qwe|qqq|www
```

Would return:

```
456|qwe|qqq|www
789|qwe|qqq|www
```

Comment: Can you show some example data?

Comment: Sure, let me add it. Just trying to figure out how to put a table in here...

Comment: Paste in a text table (don't try to make a markdown or HTML table), highlight it and ctl-k to format it as a preformatted/code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you have `NOT IN` (results that are repeated 39 times or less), but you want `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 40`

You can try:

```
SELECT tba.*
FROM table tba
  INNER JOIN (SELECT a, b, c, d
               FROM table
              GROUP BY a, b, c, d
              HAVING COUNT(*) < 40
   ) as tbb ON tbb.a = tba.a AND tbb.b = tba.b AND tbb.c = tba.c AND tbb.d = tba.d
```

This way you don't need to change the HAVING.

Comment: Thanks! This was MUCH faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
SELECT * 
FROM table as a 
inner join (SELECT CONCAT(a,b,c,d) as result, count(*) as c
FROM table
group by result) as r on CONCAT(a,b,c,d) = r.result
where c < 40